# How to generate calldata for a function

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, abi, calldata

I have got as far as generating the method ID for the function:

`function transfer(address src, address dst, uint256 amount);`

The method ID would be:

`bytes4(keccak256("transfer(address,address,uint256)")) // 0xbeabacc8`

How do I pass the function variables (on-chain) along with the method ID to a function:

`function execute(address _target, bytes _data)`

Where `_data` is the calldata  of the `transfer` function.

Comment: Are you trying to call this on-chain or off-chain?

Comment: This is an on-chain call, will update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can execute the call the following way ([members of addresses](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.3/types.html#members-of-addresses), [abi.encode*](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.3/miscellaneous.html#global-variables), [low-level calls](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.3/yul.html#evm-dialect))):

**Example 1: Call using already calculated function signature** (this answers your question)

---

```
bytes memory transferPayload = abi.encodeWithSelector(bytes4(0xbeabacc8), param1, param2, param3);
bytes memory executePayload = abi.encodeWithSignature("execute(address,bytes)", transferContractAdr, transferPayload);
(bool success, bytes memory returnData) = address(executeContractAdr).call(executePayload);
require(success, "low-level call of function execute failed [transfer(address,address,uint256), param1, param2, param3]");
```

**Example 2: Call function and let Solidity automatically calculate the function signature**

---

Just replace

```
bytes memory transferPayload = abi.encodeWithSelector(bytes4(0xbeabacc8), param1, param2, param3);
```

with

```
bytes memory transferPayload = abi.encodeWithSignature("transfer(address,address,uint256)", param1, param2, param3);
```

---

note 1: Please consider which call (call, callcode, delegatecall, staticcall) will be appropriate for your scenario

note 2: Replace the require statement with an appropriate [try-catch](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.3/control-structures.html#try-catch) block

note 3: If you call a function in the same contract, you can use `address(this)`

Answer (score 2):

For on-chain transactions, you can use `abi.encodeWithSelector`. [This](https://medium.com/@libertylocked/what-are-abi-encoding-functions-in-solidity-0-4-24-c1a90b5ddce8) article has a ton of great information about it.

In your case, you can  do the following:

```
bytes4 methodSig = 0xbeabacc8;
address addressOne = address(0);
address addressTwo = address(1);
uint256 uintOne = 2;
abi.encodeWithSelector(
    methodSig,   
    addressOne,
    addressTwo,
    uintOne
);
```

See [the official Solidity docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.3/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=encodewithselector#abi-encoding-and-decoding-functions) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

**Example 3: Use an [interface](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/contracts.html#interfaces) and let Solidity handle the encodings for you**

---

```
interface IExecute {
    function execute(address _target, bytes calldata _data) external;
}

bytes memory transferPayload = abi.encodeWithSignature(
    "transfer(address,address,uint256)",
    from, to, amount
);

IExecute(executeContractAddress).execute(
    transferContractAddress,
    transferPayload
);
```

Or even better, (this may not apply if you have specific logic in your `execute` function)

**Example 4: Skip the execute contract altogether and create a direct interface**

---

```
interface ITransfer {
    function transfer(address src, address dst, uint256 amount) external;
}

ITransfer(transferContractAddress).transfer(from, to, amount);
```